# Calculator uncaught typeerror cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

Have typed up a building calculator but for some reason it's not identifying the object at the end of the Calculate. have tried moving the function around to see if the it was incorrectly ordered when trying to pull from the function and have also removed the Number5 and all associated lines but the error came up with Number4 being the issue which makes me believe it's the closing off that is the issue.

```js
function Calculate(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7) {
                var total;
                var buildRate
                switch (n1) {
                    case "Double Brick":
                        buildRate = 1290 * n2;
                        break;
                    case "Brick Veneer":
                        buildRate = 1160 * n2;
                        break;
                    case "Weather Board":
                        buildRate = 950 * n2;
                        break;
                    case "Other":
                        buildRate = 900 * n2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                total = buildRate + (n3 * 1) + (n4 * 1) + (n5 * 1) + (n6 * 1) + (n7 * 1);
                return total;
            }
```

```html
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Construction">CONSTRUCTION TYPE:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="Construction" id="Construction">
                            <option value="Double Brick">Double Brick</option>
                            <option value="Brick Veneer">Brick Veneer</option>
                            <option value="Weather Board">Weather Board</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>AREA OF HOME [SQ METRES]:
                    </td>
                    <td> <input type="number" name="Area" id="Area" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>GARAGE, DRIVEWAYS:
                    </td>
                    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number1" id="Number1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>FENCES, GATES:
                    </td>
                    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number2" id="Number2" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>INGROUND SWIMMING POOL:
                    </td>
                    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number3" id="Number3" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>ARCHITECTS FEES, DEBRIS REMOVAL:
                    </td>
                    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number4" id="Number4" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>PERMANENT FIXTURES - SHEDS AIR CONDITIONING UNIS:
                    </td>
                    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number5" id="Number5" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>COST OF CONSTRUCTION: </td>
                    <td>$<input type="number" name="Cost"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="document.getElementById('Cost').value =
                            Calculate(document.getElementById('Construction').value, 
                            document.getElementById('Area').value,
                            document.getElementById('Number1').value,
                            document.getElementById('Number2').value,
                            document.getElementById('Number3').value,
                            document.getElementById('Number4').value,
                            document.getElementById('Number5').value)" />
    
    
    
            <input type="reset" value="&nbsp; Clear &nbsp; " onclick="location.reload();" />
```

Comment: Your document doesn't contain an element having `id` valued as "cost". Notice, that `name !== id`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the id on:

```
<input type="number" name="Cost"/>
```

In order to get its value with

```
document.getElementById('Cost').value
```

You have to add the id attribute:

```
<input type="number" name="Cost" id="Cost" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Didn't need the getElement part of the Cost.value.
`<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick= "Cost.value =`

Comment: Don't trust on names/ids representing the elements, always use a proper getter or query.

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add id in cost input also you can also get value in js function like i did

```js
function Calculate() {
  n1 = document.getElementById('Construction').value;
  n2 = document.getElementById('Area').value;
  n3 = document.getElementById('Number1').value;
  n4 = document.getElementById('Number2').value;
  n5 = document.getElementById('Number3').value;
  n6 = document.getElementById('Number4').value;
  n7 = document.getElementById('Number5').value;
  var total;
  var buildRate
  switch (n1) {
    case "Double Brick":
      buildRate = 1290 * n2;
      break;
    case "Brick Veneer":
      buildRate = 1160 * n2;
      break;
    case "Weather Board":
      buildRate = 950 * n2;
      break;
    case "Other":
      buildRate = 900 * n2;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  total = buildRate + (n3 * 1) + (n4 * 1) + (n5 * 1) + (n6 * 1) + (n7 * 1);
  return total;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="Construction">CONSTRUCTION TYPE:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="Construction" id="Construction">
        <option value="Double Brick">Double Brick</option>
        <option value="Brick Veneer">Brick Veneer</option>
        <option value="Weather Board">Weather Board</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AREA OF HOME [SQ METRES]:
    </td>
    <td> <input type="number" name="Area" id="Area" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GARAGE, DRIVEWAYS:
    </td>
    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number1" id="Number1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>FENCES, GATES:
    </td>
    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number2" id="Number2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>INGROUND SWIMMING POOL:
    </td>
    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number3" id="Number3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ARCHITECTS FEES, DEBRIS REMOVAL:
    </td>
    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number4" id="Number4" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PERMANENT FIXTURES - SHEDS AIR CONDITIONING UNIS:
    </td>
    <td>$<input type="number" name="Number5" id="Number5" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COST OF CONSTRUCTION: </td>
    <td>$<input type="number" name="Cost" id="Cost" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="document.getElementById('Cost').value = Calculate() " />



<input type="reset" value="&nbsp; Clear &nbsp; " onclick="location.reload();" />
```